# Fill param implicit object

Tags: jsf, parameters

I have a commandLink that do a POST, and the action listener in the bean fill the request map with a new parameter like this

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("confirmationWindowMessage","test");
```

In the view if I make `#{param['confirmationWindowMessage']}` nothing is presented. Why is this happening?
The action listener does not redirect to another view, so the view is the same.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't fill the `#{param}` object. This is a client-controlled map. Moreover, any attempt should go through `getRequestParameterMap()`, not `getRequestMap()`. The `getRequestMap()` represents the request attribtues, not request parameters.

Request attributes are just available by `#{attributeName}`. Thus, in your particular case so:

```
<p>#{confirmationWindowMessage}</p>
```

An alternative is to just make it a property of a request scoped bean. Or perhaps even better, a faces message.